# How can I serialize Jackson's JsonNode object?

Tags: memcached, jackson

I am replacing an in-house caching system with memcached but memcached client cannot cache the `JsonNode` objects since they don't implement `Serializable`. 
Is there any way you can achieve serializing a `JsonNode` object? Does Jackson provide `Serializable` equivalent of this class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSON is best serialized by writing it out as bytes. In Jackson, it is done using `ObjectMapper`, for example by:

```
byte[] raw = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(root);
```

MemCache does not really need Serializable since it's all raw bytes; although Java clients may try to be helpful and handle serialization.

Comment: I came here and then I realised I screwed up, because I wanted to cache the *actual json* (String) instead of JsnNode (object). Might be useful for someone who fell into the same trap :)

Comment: @Xorty right, that's a common mistake. No need to build object representation for caching things, most of the time.