# Getting NotSerializableException error in storm topology

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-storm, kryo

Storm Version: 1.2.1, 
Java Version: 8

I am writing a storm topology in scala, and started to get following error when running it in cluster mode. I was able to get the same in `LocalCluster` mode as well with config: `conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_TESTING_ALWAYS_TRY_SERIALIZE, Boolean.box( true))`. Following is the trace:

```
2018-05-05 00:49:59,342 ERROR util [Thread-37-disruptor-executor[6 6]-send-queue] Async loop died!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:522) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:487) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:74) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$consume_loop_STAR_$fn__4492.invoke(disruptor.clj:84) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.write(SerializableSerializer.java:41) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:534) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoValuesSerializer.serializeInto(KryoValuesSerializer.java:44) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoTupleSerializer.serialize(KryoTupleSerializer.java:44) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$assert_can_serialize.invoke(worker.clj:133) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$mk_transfer_fn$fn__5204.invoke(worker.clj:213) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$start_batch_transfer__GT_worker_handler_BANG_$fn__4882.invoke(executor.clj:314) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4475.onEvent(disruptor.clj:41) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:509) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.write(SerializableSerializer.java:38) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:534) ~[kryo-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoValuesSerializer.serializeInto(KryoValuesSerializer.java:44) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoTupleSerializer.serialize(KryoTupleSerializer.java:44) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$assert_can_serialize.invoke(worker.clj:133) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$mk_transfer_fn$fn__5204.invoke(worker.clj:213) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$start_batch_transfer__GT_worker_handler_BANG_$fn__4882.invoke(executor.clj:314) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__4475.onEvent(disruptor.clj:41) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:509) ~[storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    ... 6 more
```

As it seems storm is trying to serialize `ObjectNode`, which is not able to do and giving `NotSerializableException`.

Should not `ObjectNode` be `serializable`? I see a old discussion on this [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/18), but feel this should had been `serializable`.

I tried adding following in the storm config, but did not help.

```
conf.registerSerialization(classOf[com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode])
```

I also tried adding `conf.setSkipMissingKryoRegistrations(false)`, but again no rescue.

What can be proper solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Getting inspiration from @Stig's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189597/1610034) and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984055/1610034), I serialised the object's whenever passing this between the bolts instead of my objects. So now I send array of bytes like this in my bolts:

```
val messages = input.asInstanceOf[TupleImpl].get("Request").asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]].getObj[List[myObject]]
val objMapper = new ObjectMapper()
messages.foreach(message => collector.emit(new Values(objMapper.writeValueAsBytes(message))))
```

### Edit 1:

Another possible way to fix this seems like(didn't tried, I solved by sending bytes) is to write a serialiser class for the object you are passing from one bolt to another as described [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/18388/storm-serialization-with-avro-using-kryo-serialize.html). Following is a sample serialiser from this link:

```
public class StockAvroSerializer extends Serializer<Stock> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StockAvroSerializer.class);
    private Schema SCHEMA = Stock.getClassSchema();

    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, Stock object) {
        DatumWriter<Stock> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(SCHEMA);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
        try {
            writer.write(object, encoder);
            encoder.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.toString(), e);
        }
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        byte[] outBytes = out.toByteArray();
        output.writeInt(outBytes.length, true);
        output.write(outBytes);
    }

    public Stock read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<Stock> type) {
        byte[] value = input.getBuffer();
        SpecificDatumReader<Stock> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(SCHEMA);
        Stock record = null;
        try {
            record = reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(value, null));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.toString(), e);
        }
        return record;
    }
}
```

### Edit 2:

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jackson-user/yw0ZALkikkw/JvPjgCAcAgAJ) is I found why ObjectNode can not be serialised:

> `JsonNode` does not know how to serialize itself with only information available at serialization: there is no ObjectMapper or JsonGenerator to use; latter is the component it must have to serialize itself (and contents if any). It can not and should try to instantiate either (how should they be configured?); and static singletons tend to cause problems in bigger systems (one part tries to go and configure them one way, another different)

But that is quite old communication, in new version, I believe there should be some mechanism to make it serialisable.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectNode` isn't serializable (it doesn't implement the Serializable interface).

`conf.setSkipMissingKryoRegistrations(false)` is the default setting. See https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Serialization.html, which described what this property does. I don't think you want to change it in your case.

Adding `conf.registerSerialization(ObjectNode.class);` to the topology config should work, not sure why it doesn't for you. If you can't get it to work, you can work around it by serializing to e.g. Map or String before emitting the value.